# Do I have to be a certain race to be a certain class, like WoW?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, new-players, class, races

I don't know for sure if I can be any class with any race in 4th edition. Like WoW, you have to be like a Human or Dwarf in order to be a paladin.

Comment: Nitpick: Hasn't been just Human/Dwarf for Paladins in a long time. http://www.wowhead.com/news=174515/cataclysm-new-class-race-combinations - I don't think WoD changed anything.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

NO!

All racial limits are turned off in 4e for classes.

There are no restrictions for who or what you can be based on race. There are some slight limits based on alignment, but those don't mean much and have little mechanical impact so they can safely be ignored.

Comment: Additionally, while some races tend to be evil in 4e, not all of them are. So you could be a Githyanki Paladin of Pelor, if you can somehow justify this in a backstory. And size matters not either; feel free to roll up a Pixie Fighter.

Comment: Might not hurt to mention that some Themes and Epic Destinies, which are similar to classes, *do* have racial restrictions.

Answer (score 8):

No, you don't need to, but some races are better at the job.

This is usually a matter of having bonuses to the right ability scores, or having racial powers or feats that synergize with the class.

I think that's true of every D&D edition past 2e (where only humans could be paladins), at least for base classes (prestige classes, just like paragon paths in 4e, can have racial requirements).

Comment: 3.5 has a couple of race-specific prestige classes (Dwarven Defender for instance) and had some racial substitution levels (eg., if you're a Kobold, you can take a racial variant Rogue level and get "Evasion + take a move action to get out of the blast" instead of just evasion). I _do_ seem to recall a couple of splat books with race-specific classes, but splat books were ... questionable ... anyway.